# How to display a progressbar when loading a new android fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, progress-bar, fragment

I am using fragments to display the information to the user.
Question is. Four of the fragments need to load a lot of information before they are displayed. How can i show a spinning progress bar (not locking the UI-thread) while i fetch the data for the fragment?

Should i create a fragment called ProgressBar that only contains a progress bar. Then show this fragment while i load the new fragment in another thread?

Seems a bit silly to have the progress bar in each of the fragments or is this the normal approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would suffice to display indeterminate progress similar to how ListFragment does it out of the box. Don't think of it as loading the fragment though. You're waiting for the fragment's data to load. The Fragment loads immediately, displays an indeterminate progress bar, then registers a callback that will later fire and populate its UI with the retrieved data.

Comment: Should i then create a progressbar in each view that i then toggle on or off? I want to give the users a chance to back out of the operation if it takes to long.

Comment: Usually, the user cancel indeterminate progress by pressing the back button. When there are several fragments on the screen this scenario doesn't really apply to the individual tasks, but to all of them. Unless you want to do a custom thing and put a cancel button in each fragment, you're going to have to hook the back button at the activity level then broadcast a signal to each fragment to cancel the loading.

Answer (score 0):

you should put in your fragment life cycle callback while you doing lost of stuff 
I think onCreateView just create progress bar use asyn task for long running task then stop progrss bar this is general way i think people used.

thanks

Comment: Question is still, should i create a progressbar in each view xml and hide that one? or is it a better way of doing it so i don't have to always have a progressbar in each view?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a seperate `<view>` in each of the fragment to show progress in each fragment. This way it will not freeze the other fragment and also it will not freeze the user. Fragments are useful only if the users are not halted.